# python list mutation (for in loop vs range(len))

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

why does the below not mutate the passed in list:

```
def modify(listarg):
    for x in listarg:
        x=x*2
```

whereas this does mutate it:

```
def modify(listarg):
    for x in range(len(listarg)):
        listarg[x]=listarg[x]*2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one just gives you the iterated variable (`x`), essentially `for...in` uses built-in `iter` function. In the second case you actually bind value to list.

```
for x in listarg:
  x=x*2
```

The code above can be seen as:

```
i = iter(listarg)
x = i.next() # fetch first value
# this value then you double
# which won't effect the element
```

For further details you can refer this [article](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```
def modify(listarg):
    for x in listarg:
        x=x*2
```

Here `x` is just a variable, it has nothing to do with the `x` you're iterating on. It's like writing:

```
def modify(listarg):
    for x in listarg:
        y=x*2
```

In your second code, you're trying to modify the list itself.

Comment: If x is just a variable and has nothing to do with the x i'm iterating on, why then if i print x do i get the x's that i'm iterating on?

Comment: Because when you do that you're just printing `x`, not trying to assign to it. When you try to assign to it, Python automatically makes the distinguish between `x` you're iterating on, and `x` you're assigning to.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what exactly the for loop is truly iterating over ... It would appear it is not the reference to the list object but a copy.

Answer (score 0):

The first simply rebinds the variable called `x` to an object whose value is double the value of the current list element. It does not do anything at all to the list.

The second modifies the list by directly assigning to its elements.

Here is another way to modify the list:

```
def modify(listarg):
  listarg[:] = [el * 2 for el in listarg]
```

Here, the `[:]` is important; without it, we'd be creating a new list instead of replacing the contents of the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how variables are named in python (i.e. how memory works).

In the first case, you create a variable named `x`. Over time, you repeatedly assign to it, the value of whatever is in the list. After assigning it a value from the list, you assign it twice that value. At this point, you're still talking about `x` - you've read the value from the list and assigned it to `x`, and later assign twice `x`'s value to `x`. So let's take a look at this with the code:

```
def modify(listarg):
    for x in listarg:  # read a value from the list, and assign it as the value of the variable called x
        x=x*2  # x is now 2x
```

The key thing to keep in mind is that there is a space in memory for names, and a space in memory for values (suppose `listarg = [1,2]`):

step      name side      value side      code
1           x              1              for x in listarg
2.          x              2              x = x*2
3.          x              2              for x in listarg
4.          x              4              x = x*2

So you see, only the value of `x` is being changed. Never the values in `listarg`

In the second case, you are directly accessing parts of `listarg` and changing their values:

step      name side      value side      code
1.         listarg         [1,2]
           x               0             for x in range(len(listarg))
2.         x               0
           listarg         [2,2]         listarg[x] = listarg[x]*2

I'll stop tracing the execution here, to make my point:
You are accessing the 0-th "compartment" (or index) of `listarg` and modifying the value that is assigned to it. The value that `listarg[x]` holds is being changed, not the value of some other variable (such as `x`)

Hope this helps